# How can I reset a sequence in Oracle to value 1 once at the beginning of the year?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, reset

I have a table for REPORTS.

Every time a report is validated I'm using a trigger to update the table REPORT_SERIAL_NUMBER using the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SSM_ANDROID"."REPORTS_SERIAL_NUMBER_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Once per year, on the first report that gets validated I have to reset the sequence to 1.

I can use a cronjob on the server that runs on 1st of January every year. But, what it that server is down? I know, I am a bit pessimistic.

Another way I can do this is by checking every time for the date of the last report, if is not in the same year as SYSDATE then reset sequence. But, regarding performance, is not so suited.

Can it be done from the database automatically?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Instead you can go for custom method / SP for generating the sequence and have these check within it.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. But I don't want to check every time if the last added and validated report has that same year as the system. My opinion is that it's a lack of performance. I am no expert in Oracle DB.

Comment: I think you are using sequences for things they are not designed for. Do you expect your serial numbers to be gap free?

Comment: I need incremented integers as serial number for a period of one year. After that the serial number must reset to 1 on first report that is validated. I am not using it for primary keys. When a report is validated a pdf is created, I must have incremented serial number on each pdf. I am using a trigger when a report is validated to update the next serial number. I hope I made myself clear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a database job using Oracle Scheduler to do it

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034

Comment: This is great, looks like a cron job in unix. I will look further into it. Thanks!

Comment: Because I don't have the necessarily privileges to run a Scheduler I will use [DBMS_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68001/dbms_job.htm) . I just need a way to send emails when the job succeeded.